# Rmagick memory allocation failed for tif files

Tags: ruby, freebsd, tiff, rmagick

Using this...

- FreeBsd (10.2)
- Rmagick (2.15.2)
- ImageMagick (1.6.9.2.4,1)

I have successfully been reading images from s3 for weeks

```
image = Magick::ImageList.new
urlimage = open(image_locator) # Image Remote URL
image.from_blob(urlimage.read)
```

and suddenly a 1MB tiff is causing this error...

```
Magick::ImageMagickError|message="memory allocation failed `' @ error/psd.c/ReadPSDChannel/1094"
```

**UPDATE**
The Tiff files that were crashing things were

- 18 bit
- cmyk
- layered

When I make them 8 bit, rgb and flat in photoshop they work.  I am able to get 2/3rds of the way there with this.

```
convert <filepath> -colorspace sRGB -flatten -depth 8 <filepath>
```

This almost works, it's not flattening.  Any idea what about -flatten is incorrect?

**ADDITIONAL**
The output of pkg info ImageMagick

ImageMagick-6.9.2.4,1
Name           : ImageMagick
Version        : 6.9.2.4,1
Installed on   : Tue Oct 13 09:52:10 PDT 2015
Origin         : graphics/ImageMagick
Architecture   : freebsd:10:x86:64
Prefix         : /usr/local
Categories     : perl5 graphics
Licenses       : APACHE20
Maintainer     : kwm@FreeBSD.org
WWW            : http://www.ImageMagick.org/
Comment        : Image processing tools
Options        :
        16BIT_PIXEL    : on
        BZIP2          : on
        DJVU           : off
        DOCS           : on
        FFTW           : on
        FONTCONFIG     : on
        FPX            : on
        FREETYPE       : on
        GRAPHVIZ       : off
        GSLIB          : off
        HDRI           : off
        JBIG           : on
        JPEG           : on
        JPEG2000       : on
        LCMS2          : on
        LQR            : on
        LZMA           : on
        MODULES        : on
        OPENEXR        : off
        OPENMP         : off
        PANGO          : off
        PDF            : on
        PERL           : on
        PNG            : on
        SVG            : on
        TESTS          : off
        THREADS        : on
        TIFF           : on
        WEBP           : on
        WMF            : on
        X11            : on
Shared Libs required:
        liblqr-1.so.0
        libfftw3.so.3
        libXext.so.6
        libjpeg.so.8
        libfreetype.so.6
        libcairo.so.2
        libICE.so.6
        libxml2.so.2
        libwebp.so.5
        libXt.so.6
        libwmflite-0.2.so.7
        libjbig.so.2
        libSM.so.6
        libtiff.so.5
        libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
        libgio-2.0.so.0
        libltdl.so.7
        libX11.so.6
        libglib-2.0.so.0
        libgobject-2.0.so.0
        libfpx.so.2
        libperl.so.5.20
        librsvg-2.so.2
        libpng16.so.16
        libintl.so.8
        libopenjp2.so.7
        libfontconfig.so.1
        liblcms2.so.2
Shared Libs provided:
        libMagick++-6.so.6
        libMagickWand-6.so.2
        libMagickCore-6.so.2
Annotations    :
        cpe            : cpe:2.3:a:imagemagick:imagemagick:6.9.2.4:::::freebsd10:x64
        repo_type      : binary
        repository     : pkgng
Flat size      : 25.9MiB

Answer (score 1):

najd,

Can you post the package options for ImageMagick?

You can type:

```
pkg info ImageMagick
```

I would first check to see if OpenMP is off.

For flatten, have you tried adding -flatten at the end? It might be argument position sensitive.